# A Problem on the Center of Mass of a Surface of Revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

This is not a homework. I am currently solving a problem in the book, entitled, "Calculus with Analytic Geoemtry, 4th ed", by Protter and Protter. The problem is as follows:

Number 19 at page 345.

The arc
$$
C=\{(x,y):x^2=3-y, 1\leq y \leq 2\}
$$
is revolved about the y-axis. Find the center of mass of the surface generated.

**My SOLUTION**

We denote the center of mass by $(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z})$. Then clearly $\overline{x}=0=\overline{z}$. Now,
$$
ds=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx=\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx.
$$
Thus, the surface area is given by
$$
SA=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi x\ ds=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx.
$$
Thus, we get
$$
SA=\frac{\pi}{6}(27-5\sqrt{5}).
$$
The formula for $\overline{y}$ is given by
$$
\overline{y}=\frac{\overline{y}SA}{SA},
$$
where
$$
\overline{y}SA=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}y\ 2\pi x\ ds=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}(3-x^2)\ 2\pi x\sqrt{1+4x^2}dx.
$$
I have computed the above integral (its too long to show here) and get
$$
\overline{y}SA=\frac{\pi}{60}(513-125\sqrt{5})
$$
and this answer is also verified in WolframAlpha.com. I tried all possible solutions and obtained the same answers. But I cant get the answer in the book. The answer is given by
$$
\overline{y}=\frac{723}{26}.
$$
The book is already in its 4th edition, so I think I got incorrect solutions for which I could not find them. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The book's answer is not between $1$ and $2$. That's a pretty strong signal that the answer is an error.

Comment: @ David K Thanks for the nice observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  y &= 3-x^2 \\
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= -2x \\
  \frac{ds}{dx} &= \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2} \\
  &= \sqrt{1+4x^2} \\
  \bar{y} &= \frac{\iint y\, dA}{\iint dA} \\
  &= \frac{2\pi \int y\,x \, ds}
          {2\pi \int x\, ds} \\
  &= \frac{\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}} (3-x^2)x\sqrt{1+4x^2} \, dx}
          {\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}} x\sqrt{1+4x^2} \, dx} \\
  &= \frac{\frac{1}{120}(513-125\sqrt{5})}
          {\frac{1}{12}(27-5\sqrt{5})} \\
  &= \frac{5363-405\sqrt{5}}{3020} \\
  &\approx 1.47596
\end{align*}